# Python: how to check if one string in a list is part of any strings in anther list

Tags: python, string, comparison

my code works like this if

```
listOne = ['hello','hi','bye']
listTwo = ['goodbye','bye']

for x in range(0,len(listOne))
    listOne[x] in listTwo
```

`>>>True`

but consider this situation:

```
listOne = ['hello','hi','bye']
listTwo = ['goodbye','by']

for x in range(0,len(listOne):
    listOne[x] in listTwo

>>>False
```

My need is to find if strings in listTwo are part of strings in listOne. However, I need to have each loop checking one item in listOne to all in listTwo on each instance

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Try this way:

```
listOne = ['hello','hi','bye']
listTwo = ['goodbye','by']

for x in listTwo:
    if any(x in e for e in listOne):
        print(x)
```

it will print 'by', as 'by' is part of 'bye' in `listOne` .

Answer (score 0):

```
listOne = ['hello','hi','bye']
listTwo = ['goodbye','by', 'bye']

for x in listOne:
    for y in listTwo:
        if y in x:
            print(x, y, True)
        else:
            print(x, y, False)
```

Output

```
hello goodbye False
hello by False
hello bye False
hi goodbye False
hi by False
hi bye False
bye goodbye False
bye by True
bye bye True
```

Answer (score 0):

*easiest way to solve*

```
any( x for x in listTwo if  x in listOne)
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to match strings by partial match.

You can use `list(string)` to break a string up into individual characters and compare them per character if that's what you want.

Example:

```
bye = list('bye')
goodbye = list('goodbye')
lettersMatched = 0

for x in range(len(bye)):
    for y in range(len(goodbye)):
        if bye[x] == goodbye[y]:
            lettersMatched += 1

>>>lettersMatched
   3
```

This allows you to set a requirement of minimum characters to match, don't use this code though, it's just for the concept. This would match anagrams as well. You'd probably be better off using *regular expressions*. You can make a regex with the smaller word as a pattern if you wanted to, for instance, match 'bye' with 'goodbye'.

Another use would be that you can use `re.match('b?y?e?')` as a pattern to match 'bye' with 'by' but since it treats each character as optional it would also match with 'be'.

Hopefully these ideas are helpful to you! :)

Answer (score 0):

> One line solution :

```
print([item for item in listTwo for match in listOne if item in match])
```

output:

```
['by']
```

> Detailed solution :

```
for item in listTwo:
    for match in listOne:
        if item in match:
            print(item)
```